# How to Update a JLabel Displaying an Image in a While Loop?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, sockets, bufferedimage

So, I'm trying to create a very simple remote viewer, and right now that basically consists of a client that takes a screenshot, sends that to the server, the server turns that into an image and saves it as `image.jpg`, and then displays that, and then repeat every three seconds.

Everything works fine until we get to the displaying part. When I originally load the program, if I set the image box to show `image.jpg`, it works (so long as `image.jpg` already exists - aka the program has run more than once). However, when I try to set it/update it via my `Runnable`, it doesn't work.

**Note:** items do update when you put them in Runnables, so that's clearly not the issue.

Here's the server code (receiving the byte array of the image):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Get client and receive byte array
                ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2282);
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                DataInputStream inputData = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
                // Read bytes to byte array
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                for (int s; (s = inputData.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                  baos.write(buffer, 0, s);
                }
                byte result[] = baos.toByteArray();
                // Create bufferedImage from byte array
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
                bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
                // Save image
                File outputfile = new File("image.jpg");
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", outputfile);
                // Update image box
                BufferedImage imageIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
                BufferedImage resizedImage = resize(imageIcon, 440, 820); // Resizes image with parameters of (BufferedImage img, int height, int width)
                imageBox = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
                imageBox.setBounds(10, 11, 826, 446);
                frame.getContentPane().add(imageBox);
                // Close everything
                server.close();
                socket.close();
                inputData.close();
                baos.close();
                bais.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
});
thread.start();
```

And though I highly doubt there is anything wrong with the client, I've provided that as well should you want it;

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("started");
    // Capture the image
    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);

    // Convert the image to a byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    // Send byte array over socket connection
    Socket socket = new Socket("CamdensProgrammingDesktop", 2282);
    DataOutputStream outputData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    outputData.write(bytes);
    socket.close();
    outputData.close();

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
}
```

So, if you run that code, you should get an `image.jpg` being created every three seconds, but why won't the image box update?

Comment: Answer further edited, now with working code example. Again, please ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You've got several problems in the code above:

- You're creating Swing components and updating the main GUI (a JFrame) from within a background thread -- not safe. Use a SwingWorker to help you keep code that needs to be in the background separate from code that needs to be called on the Swing event thread (the EDT). Please see the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the details on why this is an important problem and how a SwingWorker can help you fix it.
- You're adding a component to a container and not calling revalidate or repaint on the container
- You're calling `setBounds(...)` on a Swing component, suggesting that you're using a null layout somewhere in the GUI, and something you definitely don't want to do as this makes debugging, updating and enhancing the GUI very difficult, and risks your program not displaying well on other platforms.
- You're creating a new JLabel needlessly -- keep one single displaying JLabel, and put it into the GUI. Then after you create the image, simply swap the label's icon. No need for repaint or revalidate when you do this.

Myself, I would create a `SwingWorker<Void, Icon>`, have it produce image icons from within the `doInBackground()` method, and then pump the icons to the GUI using the workers publish/process method pair.

For example:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Icon> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Icon>() {
    // this is called in background thread
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        boolean connectionStillGood = true;
        while (connectionStillGood) {
            //....
            // code to get image data from socket goes here
            // ....
            // update connectionStillGood value

            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(....);
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
            publish(icon);  // send icon to process method
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void process(List<Icon> chunks) {
        for (Icon icon : chunks) {
            imageBox.setIcon(icon);
        }
    }

};
worker.execute();
```

---

A more concrete example (be sure to start the ImageReceiver class first):

---

#### ImageReceiver.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageReceiver extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final int PORT_ADDR = 4040;
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private JLabel imageBox = new JLabel();

    public ImageReceiver() {
        MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new WorkerListener());
        worker.execute();
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageBox);
        scrollPane.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private class WorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
                MyWorker worker = (MyWorker) evt.getSource();
                try {
                    worker.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Icon> {
        // this is called in background thread
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT_ADDR);
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();) {

                while (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(is);
                    if (img != null) {
                        publish(new ImageIcon(img));
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw e;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Icon> chunks) {
            for (Icon icon : chunks) {
                imageBox.setIcon(icon);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Receiver");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new ImageReceiver());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

---

#### ImageProducer.java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageProducer {
    public static final String BASE = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/";
    public static final String[] IMG_PATHS = { 
            "7/74/VELEZ_SARSFIELD.png",
            "c/c4/Princeton_Univ_pub-mark.png", 
            "9/92/Union_escudo_antiguo.png", 
            "8/88/Faelog.jpg",
            "8/84/Club-social-y-deportivo-mu%C3%B1iz.png", 
            "0/08/6931st_CSC.jpg",
            "f/ff/Coat_of_arms_of_Mielec.png", 
            "6/64/Francocanadiense.jpg",
            "5/58/Kitty_cat_council.jpg", 
            "thumb/1/12/Cear2002.jpg/400px-Cear2002.jpg",
            "9/94/Wappen_von_Arkantos.png", 
            "3/39/Escudo_chaca_Taq.png", 
            "a/a2/USBCcrest.jpg",
            "0/07/351st_Avn_Co_pocket_patch_1.jpg", 
            "0/06/Steinbach_Lebach_wappen.png",
            "f/f9/90th_Avn_Co_MedHelpatch.jpg" };
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imagePath = "";
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", ImageReceiver.PORT_ADDR);
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream()) {
            for (String path : IMG_PATHS) {
                imagePath = BASE + path;
                URL inputUrl = new URL(imagePath);
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(inputUrl);
                ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", os);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Image Path: " + imagePath);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was I was creating a new `JLabel` each and every time the image was supposed to display, which wasn't working. What I did to solve this was set the `JLabel` to `image.jpg` when the program starts, then in the `while` loop, use `.setIcon()` to change the icon easily.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer (fourth bullet point), but you still have dangerous code in there, and I stand by all my other recommendations

Comment: Please see edit to answer for example and feel free to ask questions if confused